# La propiedad 'map' no existe en el tipo 'Observable<User>'

Tags: angular5, rxjs

Soy nuevo en angular y trato de trabajar con la libreria `rxjs` pero siempre me da un error que no existe el objeto Observable el cual lo importo de la siguiente manera:

`import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';` que es la forma que he visto que se importa así que se me ocurrió que se cargara el modulo completo `import {Observable} from 'rxjs';` y así obtener el observable pero después me da el error que no existe la propiedad `map` dentro del objeto observable que se carga de la siguiente manera `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';` y lo termino cargando así: `import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';` y encerrando el operador `map` dentro de un `pipe(map())`.

Porque pasa todo eso que no me dan los módulos donde se supone se encuentran y si lo hago de la manera que he estado haciéndolo no se supone que cargo todos los componentes haciendo mas lenta mi aplicación. me gustaría saber como cargarlos de manera correcta sin tener que cargar todos los componentes.

Answer (score 2):

En las nuevas versiones de **rxjs** (*actualmente la 6*) si que puedes importar tanto observables como operadores utilizando una misma ruta de *import*. Sin importar la carga que supondría al rendimiento de la app (lo gestiona internamente):

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Si no estás utilizando está versión tan reciente puedes hacer *imports* específicos:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

Answer (score 0):

En RxJS6 la forma de importar y usar los operadores ha cambiado. La forma correcta es la que has acabado usando:

```
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Y ahora los operadores no los aplicas a los observables, tienes que usar `pipe()` sobre el `Observable` y usar los operadores dentro del `pipe()`.

```
unObservable
  .pipe(
    map(num => num * 10),
    filter(value => value > 100)
  )
  .subscribe(...);
```

Es decir, que has encontrando la forma correcta.

Eso sí, no incluyas `rxjs-compat` porque es uan capa de compatibilidad con versiones anteriores de RxJS y hará tu aplicación más grande.